# What is $H_n(M,\partial M;G)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have: $$H_n(M,\partial M;G)\cong H_n(M,\partial M\times[0,1);G)\cong H_n(int(M),\partial M\times(0,1);G)\cong H^0(M-\partial M\times[0,1);G)\cong H^0(M;G)\cong Hom(G,G),$$ but I don't know what is $ Hom(G,G)$?

If the $ Hom(G,G)$ always garanties $H_n(M,\partial M;G)$ has a fundamental class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your $M$ is an orientable compact manifold of dimension $n$. The [Lefschetz duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_duality) gives you isomorphisms
$$H_k (M, \partial M; G) \cong H^{n-k} (M; G).$$
In particular,
$$H_n (M, \partial M; G) \cong H^0 (M; G).$$
It seems like in the last step you are trying to apply the [universal coefficient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem):
$$H^0 (M; G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z} (H_0 (M), G).$$
This is the group of homomorphisms $H_0 (M) \to G$. The group $H_0 (M)$ is free, and its generators correspond to the connected components of $M$. In particular, if $M$ is connected, then $H_0 (M) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H^0 (M;G) \cong G$.

(There's some mistake, you most likely mean "$\operatorname{Hom} (\mathbb{Z},G)$", not "$\operatorname{Hom} (G,G)$".)

Comment: I still want to ask if $H_n(M,\partial M;G)$ always has a fundamental class?

Comment: @6666 Sure (if the manifold is orientable), as this calculation shows that $H_n (M, \partial M; G) \cong G$.

Comment: But what if $G$ is not cyclic and without a ring structure?

Comment: $G$ in the calculations above is simply an abelian group, not a ring. I think normally by a "fundamental class" one means a generator of $H_n (M, \partial M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Or in the non-orientable case, the nontrivial element of $H_n (M, \partial M; \mathbb{Z}/2) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$.